# Find attachment by file name contains?

Tags: soql

I am using a tool (conga) to assemble files, I need to query and load the files by their name

I am using name like with no success. I wish to say get me the attachment from the record whos file name contains 'SMART'

```
SELECT Id
FROM Attachment    
WHERE ParentId = '{pv0}' Name LIKE 'SMART'
```

but it failing to find them

Getting Unknown error parsing query in the console[image]

Answer (score 1):

The valid SOQL would be:

```
... FROM Attachment 
    WHERE ParentId = 'someId' AND Name Like 'Smart%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ContentDocumnet Object Like

```
SELECT id FROM ContentDocument where title='Capture'
```

Comment: `ContentDocument` and `Attachment` aren't the same object, and this really does not directly address the issue in the question.